# Javascript: How to get user's timezone based on device?

Tags: javascript, css, datetime, timezone

I would like to get a user's timezone based on the device they are using. I'm aware that doing like, doing the following retrieves me the user's date based on the device they are using:

```
const dateToday = new Date()
dateToday.setFullYear(dateToday.getFullYear())
```

I attempted:

```
const timezone = jstz.determine()
const userTimezone = timezone.name()
```

But I would like to get back the timezone name in PDT, EST, etc. rather than America/New_York.

And `var offset = dateToday.getTimezoneOffset()` only gets me the offset.

So I was wondering in Javascript how to get a user's timezone's name based on the device user?

Thank you

**My question is not duplicate**

I did give the referred question a try but it only returns the offset in time. What I am looking for is timezone name in PDT, EST, etc. based on the user's device time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not make an array containing shortforms for each offset?

Comment: @NicolePhillips Already checked it out and that's how I attempted `.getTimezoneOffset()`, but only gets me the offset time and not timezone name.

Comment: @Jonasw Sorry but could you show an example for clarification? So I can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
var convert=["ABC","DEF"];
alert(convert[offset]);
```

This is maybe not the best answer, but its an easy way to convert the offset to your timezones string